# Can you make a self lighting object like the Sun in Unity 5.3

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 5.3.2f1 personal 64bit dx11

I am trying to make a accurate solar system model (not a hacked together one).
I am having problems lighting the Sun.
**I cant work out how to light the Sun with its own light while allowing it to give out light also.
Is this even possible?** If so any direction or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a look at using the [Emission](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterEmission.html) parameter (assuming you're using the standard shader) I'm not suggesting it's better but it may give you what you want.

Comment: Hi, I tried emission but couldn't get it to light anything. My model is 1:100,000 scale maybe things were too far away for that to work or I did it wrong. Thanks for input

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, turn off cast and receive shadows on the Sun then put a point light inside it. Still welcome to better solutions.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO7hk.png

Comment: I think if you don't want to use unity's built-in lights you would have to write your own lighting system

Comment: I may look into that, should be a fun learning experience. Thanks for input.